# How to efficiently generate matrix from vector in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a function `f(x):[0,1]-> Rⁿ` such as:

```
>>> f(0.54)
array([0.2, 0.3, 4.0, 5.2, ... , 1.0])
```

How can I efficiently apply that to a vector, in order to generate a matrix?

*Example:*

```
>>> f([0.54, 0.32, 0.56, 0.21])
array([0.2, 0.3, 4.0, 5.2, ... , 1.0],
      [0.6, 0.1, 0.0, 2.3, ... , 4.7],
      [0.1, 7.1, 0.2, 4.9, ... , 3.1],
      [1.3, 2.8, 1.2, 1.1, ... , 5.3])
```

**Note:** `numpy` solutions are very welcome :)

Comment: The issue is not about mapping, but on doing the multidimensional mapping in a efficient way.

Comment: As long as the function is black box there isn't much you can do.  A one to many mapping complicates the task. Vectorize takes signature, but is slower.  frompyfunc is my favorite.  It returns an object.  The resulting array will need stacking,.

Comment: I added a link to 'vectorize' question with a one-to-many function.